# Elasticsearch Child Mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, mapping

I haven't not been able to find the answer to this question anywhere, so I'll try my luck here.

I know that I can map fields to a specific type in ES and that works well.

But say I have an data set:

```
{
    "main":{
        "field1": "test",
        "field2": 1,
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Where the fields in main are arbitrary and change per document. What I cant seem to find is if there is a way to map all fields no matter what type they are inside main, to text. I can get it work if i explicitly map every fields, but the fields change and can be added at any time, so I can not possibly map them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic template can be used to map fields dynamically added to specific mapping. Please refer to this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) .

Comment: Thank you, not sure how I missed that.